# Ember.js routing alias

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In there a way in `Ember.js` with routing to basically create an alias route that simply goes to the same place as another route? I have the following defined:

```
this.resource("accounts", { path: "/accounts/:account_id" }, function() {
  this.route("credit", { path: "/credits/:credit_id" });
  this.route("debit", { path: "/debits/:debit_id" });
  this.route("refund", { path: "/refunds/:refund_id" });
  this.route("hold", { path: "/holds/:hold_id" });
});
```

An example working route looks like:

```
/accounts/foo-bar-account-id/credits/foo-bar-credit-id
```

I need an alias routes though for each, without account, that should work in the form of:

```
 /credits/:credit_id
 /debits/:debit_id
 /refunds/:refund_id
 /holds/:hold_id
```

Can I do something as simple as?

```
this.route("accounts.credit", { path: "/credits/:credit_id" });
this.route("accounts.debit", { path: "/debits/:debit_id" });
this.route("accounts.refund", { path: "/refunds/:refund_id" });
this.route("accounts.hold", { path: "/holds/:hold_id" });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup the conceptually Alias route to redirect in the `redirect` hook using the `transitionTo` method to redirect to what ever Route you want to be redirected to. Example:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function () {
    this.transitionTo('myAliasRoute');
  }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: What would the route look like? Would I need duplicate templates for each?

Comment: hmm, I don't think so, if the only thing you are doing is redirecting, but haven't tested your special case...

Comment: What does the route look like then in terms of the template definition? `this.route("what-goes-here", { path: "/credits/:credit_id" });`

Comment: `what-goes-here` is basically the name that will be used to lookup your templates/routes/controller if there are any, otherwise ember does create it for you, but obviously if you would go the redirect way you had to at least create the routes

Comment: If I have a route defined `this.route("aliasCredits", { path: "/credits/:credit_id" });` what does the actual route definition look like: `Balanced.AliasCredits = Balanced.AuthRoute.extend({...})`

Comment: if `aliasCredits` is not nested then yes `App.AliasCredits = ...`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29936/discussion-between-justin-and-intuitivepixel)